# Creating and modifying channels

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm trying to create a channel and immediately modify it as well as send/receive messages through it. The problem is that right after creating it, my client doesn't know it exists since it was created using a rest call. And therefore I cannot access it locally.

Is there any way to update or refresh my client/guild so that I can get the new channels?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
private async Task<bool> CreateRoom(SocketGuildUser user)
    {
        RestTextChannel introRoom = await guild.CreateTextChannelAsync($"channel-{user.Id}"); //guild is a locally saved client.getGuild() call. Need to update?

        SocketTextChannel newChannel= guild.GetChannel(introRoom.Id);

        return true;
    }
```

I've tried doing a client.getGuild() call in between creation and getting the channel but that doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

I recently started playing with the Discord so I'm not an expert but since we're dealing with an async API, you can't know exactly when the channel is created unless you handle the event that gets fired at that time. You should be able to write a handler for [channel created](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.BaseSocketClient.html#Discord_WebSocket_BaseSocketClient_ChannelCreated), in which you will update your internal data model.